# Troubleshooting "Entities passed to the choice field must be managed"

Tags: forms, symfony

This question has been asked several times on SO - and each time, the solution appears to be different, and almost always, the answer appears to have been discovered by chance/ or it is a crude hack - meaning  that there is no consistent view as to what causes the problem and how it can be fixed.

I am also encountering the message **"Entities passed to the choice field must be managed"** - and it is not clear why this exception is being raised.

I have a Contact class defined (.yml format) in a bundle. The Contact class has a manyToOne relation ship with two other classes `Promotion` and `ContactReferrer` - see below:

```
Foobar\ContactlistBundle\Entity\Contact:
    type: entity
    table: contact
    repositoryClass: Foobar\ContactlistBundle\Repository\ContactRepository

    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        first_name:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: true

        last_name:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: true

        email:
            type: string
            length: 128
            unique: true

        token:
            type: string
            length: 8
            unique: true

        is_validated:
            type: boolean

        created_at:
            type: datetime

        updated_at:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true


    manyToOne:
        promotion:
            targetEntity: Promotion
            inversedBy: promoted_contacts
            joinColumn:
                name: promotion_id
                referencedColumnName: id

        referrer:
            targetEntity: ContactReferrer
            inversedBy: referrer_contacts
            joinColumn:
                name: contact_referrer_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

I generated the form using `php app/console doctrine:generate:form FooBarContaclistBundleContact` and manually edited the form as follows:

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('first_name')
            ->add('last_name')
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add('token')
            ->add('is_validated')
            ->add('created_at')
            ->add('updated_at')
            ->add('promotion', 'entity', array(
                                                'class' => 'Foobar\ContactlistBundle\Entity\Promotion',
                                                'expanded' => false,
                                                'multiple' => false, )
                 )
            ->add('referrer', 'entity', array(
                                                'class' => 'Foobar\ContactlistBundle\Entity\ContactReferrer',
                                                'expanded' => false,
                                                'multiple' => false, )
            );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Foobar_contactlistbundle_contacttype';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Foobar\ContactlistBundle\Entity\Contact',
        );
    }
}
```

In my Entity/Contact.php class, here is the code for the constructor:

```
class Contact
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->token = 'abcdef123';
        $this->is_validated = false;
        $this->created_at =  new \DateTime();
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());

        // Set these to defaults
        $this->promotion = new \Foobar\ContactlistBundle\Entity\Promotion();
        $this->referrer = new \Foobar\ContactlistBundle\Entity\ContactReferrer();
    }

    // more code ... 
}
```

In my controller, I have the following code:

```
public function newcontactAction(Request $request)
{
    // do something ...
    $contact = new Contact();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(), $contact);  // <- Exception thrown here
    // do something ...
}
```

When I browse the route that causes the controller code above to be executed, I get the error: `Entities passed to the choice field must be managed` - Does **anyone** know what is causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

`Entities passed to the choice field must be managed` means that related entities must be persisted to entityManager. Try to persist the `promotion` and `referrer` entities before creating form

```php
public function newcontactAction(Request $request)
{
    // do something ...
    $em->persist($contact->getPromotion());
    $em->persist($contact->getReferrer());
    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(), $contact);
```

If this doesn't help you will have to create new promotion and referrer entities, persist them to entityManager, than do the `flush()`. And only after this steps create new contact entity and create Form.

Comment: I don't understand why Symfony does this